# NaN value when i choose an option in select

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

In my project I want to view a price of associated code, but in `.filter`  the selection of option doesn't work, if given the`NaN` value. How can I solve it?

- **summary.ts**

```typescript
    intervention: AssociationSt[] = []
      arr: number = 0
      selection: number[] = []
      priceEn: number = 0
    
      findPrice() {
        const priceEn = this.intervention
        .filter(c => this.selection.map(m => +m).includes(c.interv.id))
        .reduce((a,c) => a + c.association.price, 0)
        this.priceEn = priceEn
      }
```

- **summary.html**

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card my-5" *ngFor="let el of intervention; index as j">
            <div class="card-header" style="text-align: center;">
                <div [(ngModel)]="arr" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl>
                    INTERVENTION: {{el.interv.code}}
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="card-body">
                <div *ngIf="intervention[arr]">
                    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selection[j]" name="sel{{j}}">
                        <option [value]="el.interv.id" *ngFor="let el2 of intervention[arr].association; index as i">
                            {{el2.interv.code}}
                        </option>
                    </select><br>
                    <button class="btn-primary" (click)="findPrice()">prova</button><br>
                    Struct price: {{el.price}}<br>
                    En price: {{priceEn}}
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

- **AssociationSt.ts**

```typescript
interv: CodeSt
association: AssociationEn
price: number
```

- **AssociationEn.ts**

```typescript
interv: CodeEn
price: number
```

- **CodeSt.ts**

```typescript
id: number
code: string
```

- **CodeEn.ts**

```typescript
id: number
code: string
```

Comment: What your interface says does not mean your objects contains that. `console.log` is a good way to know what your object contains. Can you print a `console.log(this.selection)` at the beginning of the findPrice method ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging so far?

Comment: @Chris yeah, the debug tell me NaN after the filter and reduce method. The problem is in there

Comment: Ok... so filter first, then log. Does that give the expected result? If so, check the reduce function. Put logs inside. Do variables contain what you think they contain? etc etc.

Comment: @Random the `console.log(this.selection)` show me the id of AssociationSt, so it's correct

Comment: @ChrisG the log after the `.reduce` method is correct, show me an array. But after the `.reduce` shows me `NaN`. The error is probably here but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Can you add the code with the log() calls to your question and state exactly which log is showing what? You said "after the `.reduce`" twice, I assume you misspoke? Ideally you create a [mre] on codesandbox and post the link.

Comment: @ChrisG excuse me, I was wrong to write. **Before** `.reduce`, the log(priceEn) is the array of `AssociationSt` with its variables. **After** `.reduce` show me NaN

Comment: The most likely explanation is that one or more `c.association.price` aren't a number.